# Esp32 Turn by turn Navigation

Tags: c++, navigation, esp32, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to create an app that allows me to use my esp32 as a "GPS" for turn by turn navigation.

I searched a lot, saw a lot of projects, but couldn't understand any of them + it seens that some of those projects don't work anymore. Basically I am using BLEDevices in order to create a bluetooth connection with my esp32 and my android phone

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");

  BLEDevice::init("Long name works now");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World says Neil");
  pService->start();
  // BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();  // this still is working for backward compatibility
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(true);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);  // functions that help with iPhone connections issue
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x12);
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Characteristic defined! Now you can read it in your phone!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

the main problem is that I can't figure out which app I can use in my phone (waze,komoot, sygic ...) to get for ex the next move, speed and etc and send it to my esp32.Also I already tried different approechs like KomootBLEConnect.h, my phone connects to the esp32 bluetooth, but it don't show any information about navigation

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "KomootBLEConnect.h"

//When data is received from Komoot, this callback is triggered. Start your processing here
void NavCallback(uint8_t icon, uint32_t length, String street)
{
  Serial.printf("icon: %d, length %d, street: %s\n", icon,length,street);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting Arduino BLE Client application...");
  Komoot::BLEHandler::Begin("ESP32 Komoot");
  Komoot::BLEHandler::RegisterCallback(NavCallback);
}


void loop()
{
  Komoot::BLEHandler::Loop(); //Scans for BLE devices that serve the BLEConnect Service and connects to them IF paired
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Don't look for code. Look for documentation.

Comment: @ user4581301 can't find any docs...

Comment: See [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 0):

I had made one thing that ran with Sygic application but we have important problem here: The development team of Sygic would be remove this feature anytime.
For your refer:
https://vt.tiktok.com/ZSNLPUuWQ/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).